# put shape at intersections on rectangular grid in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs3

I have got my rectangular grid in Adobe Illustrator CS3 on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3:

[Rectangular grid:

[image: rectangular grid]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUiPM.png)

How do I make it so that it puts a shape/dot/object on the intersections, where the lines meet each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need enable the `Snap Option, and Smart Guides`

In your case, Snap to Point is the case (`View > Snap to Point`)
.
And the Smart Guides (`View > Smart Guides`)

Screen Shots:
[image]
[image]

[***I am using Illustrator CS5, but Im sure these have been there for a while, not sure since when***]

Comment: Cheers, this works. Good detailed answer. Shame I can't upvote with 3 reputation.

Answer (score 3):

`View > Snap to Point` **or** `View > Snap to Grid`

Comment: thanks, but no. Look at the image/link.

Comment: @gadgetmo this(above) should work...

Comment: I was preparing my answer with screen shots and @ueberkim answered quick and brief, good work, it should work if it doesn't there's something wrong with you software, try deleting Illustrator preferences file(google that) to reset the software to its defaults setting. Good Luck !

Comment: You have the screenshots bellow to prove that is works :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option to this is to set up a rectangular (sic!) grid (`View > Show Grid`) and work with *`iew > Snap To Grid` option set. The rectangular grid can be easily set via *AIPrefs* (Windows, CS6) or *Adobe Illustrator Cloud Prefs* (Windows, CC) or *Adobe Illustrator Prefs* (Mac, CS6) or *Adobe Illustrator Cloud Prefs* (Mac, CC) file located under *Adobe Illustrator XX Settings*. Full article on this available here: [setting up rectangular grid](http://ccmutants.com/subc/tech/rectangular_colored_grid/rectangular_colored_grid.html)

[image]

Regards,
Pawel Kuc